# Java шашки только из битовых операций

Tags: java, java-8, битовые-операции

Нужно написать игру в шашки для 2 игроков используя ввод с клавиатуры.
**Использовать можно только : инициализацию переменных, битовые/побитовые операции и операторы, петли.**
Всё остальное **нельзя**.
Нужно использовать переменные типа long биты которых буду отвечать за шашки и их описание (по 6 шашек на 1 переменную long). После каждого хода на консоль выводится доска 8х8 с шашками на ней. Все остальные правила игры как в оригинальных шашках. Набросайте хотя бы начало, я уже совсем запутался как это должно работать, спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пример вашей реализации и объясните в чем проблема.

Comment: `long whitePieces1 = 0b0000000000_100001010_100001000_100000111_100000101_100000011_100000001l;`
        Последние 10 бит не используются, у меня 6 групп по 9 бит каждая группа содержит информацию о шашке,
        я знаю, что при помощи опрератора я могу изменить характеристики определённой шашки.
        Например здесь у меня 6 шашек стоят на доске 8х8 в начальной позиции (как в правилах шашек) но как мне например
        отобразить саму таблицу на которой будут видны шашки и их позиция, если мне нельзя использовать таблицы?

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить... А что такое петли?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець судя по всему вольный перевод с аглицкого - loop, циклы ))

Answer (score 1):

Вам понадобятся методы для получения координат, цвета итд... Вот, начните с них:

```java
public class Main {
    public static final short MASK_SINGLE_PIECE = 0b111111111; // 9 bits
    public static final byte MASK_POSITION_X = 0b111;          // bits 0..2 (right-to-left)
    public static final byte MASK_POSITION_Y = 0b111000;       // bits 3..5 (right-to-left)

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long whitePieces1 = 0b0000000000_100001010_100001000_100000111_100000101_100000011_100000001L;

        System.out.println(getPiecePosX(whitePieces1, 0) + "," + getPiecePosY(whitePieces1, 0));
        System.out.println(getPiecePosX(whitePieces1, 1) + "," + getPiecePosY(whitePieces1, 1));
        System.out.println(getPiecePosX(whitePieces1, 2) + "," + getPiecePosY(whitePieces1, 2));
        System.out.println(getPiecePosX(whitePieces1, 3) + "," + getPiecePosY(whitePieces1, 3));
        System.out.println(getPiecePosX(whitePieces1, 4) + "," + getPiecePosY(whitePieces1, 4));
        System.out.println(getPiecePosX(whitePieces1, 5) + "," + getPiecePosY(whitePieces1, 5));
    }

    public static byte getPiecePosX(long piecesBits, int pieceNumber) {
        long bitsForPiece = piecesBits >> (pieceNumber * 9);
        short pieceBits = (short) (bitsForPiece & MASK_SINGLE_PIECE);
        return (byte) (pieceBits & MASK_POSITION_X);
    }

    public static byte getPiecePosY(long piecesBits, int pieceNumber) {
        long bitsForPiece = piecesBits >> (pieceNumber * 9);
        short pieceBits = (short) (bitsForPiece & MASK_SINGLE_PIECE);
        return (byte) ((pieceBits & MASK_POSITION_Y) >> 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.